# Kerberos impersonation for Hive (Beeline)

Tags: hive, kerberos, impersonation, beeline

I am trying to impersonate kerberos in order to connect to hive but it is giving gss init exception.

```
UserGroupInformation ugi = kinit.generateKerberosTicket(configResources, keytab, principal);
serGroupInformation ugiProxy =  UserGroupInformation.createProxyUser("shashi", ugi.getCurrentUser());

ugiProxy.doAs( new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>(){
            @Override
            public Void run() throws Exception {
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://quickstart.cloudera:10000/default;principal=hive/quickstart.cloudera@CLOUDERA", "shashi", "");
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                String sql = "show databases ";
                ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                if (res.next()) {
                    System.out.println("DB names ---- >" +res.getString(1));
                }

                makeHiveJdbcConnection();
                return null;
            }
```

But getting following exception .

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://quickstart.cloudera:10000/default;principal=hive/quickstart.cloudera@CLOUDERA: GSS initiate failed
```

Any clue for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

unset the hadoop proxy user first, beeline will fail if you do not unset it first